# How to change color of listView item depending on position

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-custom-view

How to change color of listView item depending on position? I can't solve this problem about 4 days. Maybe someone could help me.

I have customView class:

```
public class CustomView extends View  {

    private String[] hoursList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.hours); ;
    private String[] minutesList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.minutes);;
    private String[] dayOfTimeList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.timeOfDay);
    private ListView listView;
    private HourAdapter hourAdapter;
    private MinuteAdapter minuteAdapter;
    private DayOfTimeAdapter dayOfTimeAdapter;
    public static int middlePosition;



     public CustomView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }
    
        public CustomView(Context context, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            super(context);
            inflate(context, R.layout.custom_test, viewGroup);
    
   
            listView = viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.hours_list);
            hourAdapter = new HourAdapter(context, hoursList);
            listView.setAdapter(hourAdapter);
    
            listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
    
                                             @Override
                                             public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                                             }
    
                                             @Override
                                             public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                                              middlePosition = firstVisibleItem+1;
    
                                             }
                                         }
            );

    
        }
    }
```

and adapter class:

```
 public class HourAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater lInflater;
        private String[] hoursValueList;
    
        public HourAdapter(Context context, String[] hoursValueList{
            lInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.hoursValueList = hoursValueList;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;
          if (view == null) {
                view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
            }
    
            TextView textHours = view.findViewById(R.id.textRow);
            textHours.setText(hoursValueList[position]);
            
            if (position == CustomView.middlePosition) {
              view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected_color);
            }
    
            return view;
        }
    }

What I need: when any element is in the middle position it has another color.
```

But with code which I have now, it doesn't work. Every 2nd element is colored,
but I need  that any element which is in the middle position to be colored

[image]

Comment: whaT KIND OF PROBLEM YOU FACED?

Comment: I get result as in a picture. Element is not painted.

Comment: picture i cant see

Comment: Sorry, I added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below:

CustomAdapter.java:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private LayoutInflater lInflater;
private String[] valueList;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, String[] valueList) {
    lInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.valueList = valueList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return valueList.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return valueList[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
    }
    TextView text = view.findViewById(R.id.textRow);
    text.setText(valueList[position]);
    return view;
}
}
```

CustomView.java:

```
public class CustomView extends View {

private String[] hoursList;
private String[] minutesList;
private String[] dayOfTimeList;
private ListView hoursListView;
private ListView minutesListView;
private ListView dayOfTimeListView;
private CustomAdapter hoursAdapter;
private CustomAdapter minutesAdapter;
private CustomAdapter dayOfTimeAdapter;

AbsListView.OnScrollListener scrollListener = new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            View firstView = view.getChildAt(0);
            int offset = view.getTop() - firstView.getTop();
            if (offset > (firstView.getHeight() / 2)) {
                view.smoothScrollToPosition(view.getLastVisiblePosition());
            } else {
                view.smoothScrollToPosition(view.getFirstVisiblePosition());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        for (int i = 0; i < view.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View childView = view.getChildAt(i);
            if (i == 1) childView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE); else childView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
    }
};

public CustomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomView(Context context, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    super(context);
    inflate(context, R.layout.custom_test, viewGroup);

    hoursList = new String[26];
    hoursList[0] = " ";
    hoursList[25] = " ";
    for (int i = 1; i < hoursList.length - 1; i++) hoursList[i] = String.valueOf(i);
    minutesList = new String[62];
    minutesList[0] = " ";
    minutesList[61] = " ";
    for (int i = 1; i < minutesList.length - 1; i++) minutesList[i] = String.valueOf(i);
    dayOfTimeList = new String[4];
    dayOfTimeList[0] = " ";
    dayOfTimeList[1] = "AM";
    dayOfTimeList[2] = "PM";
    dayOfTimeList[3] = " ";

    hoursListView = viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.hours_list);
    hoursAdapter = new CustomAdapter(context, hoursList);
    hoursListView.setAdapter(hoursAdapter);
    minutesListView = viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.minutes_list);
    minutesAdapter = new CustomAdapter(context, minutesList);
    minutesListView.setAdapter(minutesAdapter);
    dayOfTimeListView = viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.dayOfTime_list);
    dayOfTimeAdapter = new CustomAdapter(context, dayOfTimeList);
    dayOfTimeListView.setAdapter(dayOfTimeAdapter);

    hoursListView.setOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
    minutesListView.setOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
    dayOfTimeListView.setOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
}
}
```

To color the 2nd element, the color of other elements need reset. Please note that, if 3 rows is displayed initially, then there may be 4 rows (2 partial displayed and 2 completely displayed) during/after scroll. The 2nd element may be off from the middle position.